# Which D&D artist drew the cover art for the Warriors of the Eternal Sun Genesis game?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, art

The [Warriors of Eternal Sun Sega Genesis game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_&_Dragons:_Warriors_of_the_Eternal_Sun) had a small portion of a full-sized poster by a D&D artist. I have seen the full-size art in some D&D art book back in the day, even saw someone that tattooed it on a full-back tattoo.

What artist drew that?

[image: Warriors of the Eternal Sun cover art.]

Fair Use rationale: the image is of low resolution, and is used with the sole purpose of identifying the artwork in the question. The quality of the question will be lower without it.

Also note that I am NOT asking something about a CRPG. It just happens that the best reference to the artwork in question (that has been used in other D&D products) is the exerpt used in the CRPG cover. Asking it here has a higher chance of reaching some old school veteran that remembers it (from other sources than the game) than asking on gaming.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This piece is also used on the cover of the [AD&D Book of Lairs](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/44041/the-book-of-lairs). In that book's credits, the cover is credited to **Clyde Caldwell**.