# Where can I find the full Clyde Caldwell artwork that appears on these covers?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, art

The art by Clyde Caldwell (identified in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34975/11402)) that was featured on the cover of both the Genesis CRPG [*Warriors of Eternal Sun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_&_Dragons:_Warriors_of_the_Eternal_Sun) and the AD&D sourcebook [*The Book of Lairs*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/44041/the-book-of-lairs) is an excerpt from a larger poster.

[image: Warriors of the Eternal Sun cover art. Fair Use rationale: the image is of low resolution, and is used with the sole purpose of identifying the artwork in the question. The quality of the question will be lower without it.]
[image: AD&D The Book of Lairs cover.]

I'm trying to track down an image of the full original painting. I know it exists because I once saw (a couple decades ago... OMG) the full poster in one of those huge "the art of AD&D-ish" coffee table art books, and even a picture of someone with the full artwork tattoed on his back.

Since the answer by [@SevenSidedDie](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/321/sevensideddie) on the original question, I have searched to no avail for a digital or physical image of the original, so again, help a fellow AD&D geek out. Thanks.

**Where can I find the full Clyde Caldwell artwork that appears on these covers?**

Comment: Have you tried contacting Caldwell directly? http://www.clydecaldwell.com/pages/contact.html has an email address.

Answer (score 5):

This is, indeed, "Dragon's Lair" by Clyde Caldwell.

A full-page version of the painting (without any text superimposed) can be found on page 119 of *The Art of Dungeons & Dragons Fantasy Game* (ISBN 0-88038-161-2)<sup>1</sup>. This book lists the original source as Dragon magazine #65.

The [artist's gallery (NFSW)](http://www.clydecaldwell.com/) doesn't have a version, but you can find it online by searching for the name. [Here's a photo that seems to be a collector who owns the original](http://www.munchkinpress.com/cpg149/displayimage.php?album=18&pos=10). As you can see, the *Book of Lairs* cover is pretty much the image, whereas the game box has been slightly cropped.

<sub>1 - It's a pretty decent art book overall if you like 80s-style D&D art like Jeff Easley and Larry Elmore. I've seen copies online for like $16. Be careful about buying "used" because the spine is *incredibly* fragile.</sub>